# moment.js returning an unexpected fromNow date when date is MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a date in the following format `var timestamp =  "6/9/2016 1:47:31 PM";`. I'm trying to get the relative time (4 hours ago, 3 minutes ago, 3 days ago, etc...) from the timestamp compared to the current datetime using from now.

```
var LastReading = moment(timestamp).fromNow();
```

but this is returning `"2010 years from now"`. I tried using the format

```
var LastReading = moment(timestamp, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

but I get the same result. Any ideas? Do I need to format the date in a different way in order to get the fromNow method to work as expected?

Comment: Which version of `moment`? Looks like it might be quite old. Also, given that timestamp, your format should be `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A`

Comment: Using your code with the current version of moment.js gives me "2 hours ago" plus a deprecation warning for your first, formatless example, and "14 hours ago" for the second version including the format string.

Comment: version is ^2.13.0

Comment: @robertklep How could you tell it was old based off of the code I posted?

Comment: @robertklep using your string format seemed to fix it for me. If you create an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match your timestamp, the format should look like this:

```
MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A
```

`HH` means 24 hour time, but you're using 12 hour time, for which you need to use `hh`. Also, `A` will match `AM/PM`.

Comment: will I have ant issues with other localizations using this method?